# difference between complexities in two different programs for data types?

Tags: c, complexity-theory

suppose in one program, I declare a statement `int inpt;`.

In another program I declare `int inpt = 0;`

what will be the difference in terms of space complexities between the two statements??
Also will the OS need extra memory cycle in the second statement above?? please if anyone can explain in detail..

Comment: Are these statements local to a function or global?

Comment: all the primitive types in C/C++/Java are instantiated to default value anyway - AFAIK, saying `int inpt = 0;` simply initialises it to 0. whereas `int inpt;` default initialises to 0. THe difference is you are being explicit about it when you say `int inpt = 0`. I cannot print out the ASM code for it, but if you disassemble the code in Visual Studio, you should see that it is really the same.

Comment: @RohitGoel       I forgot to mention that in C, it auto-initialises the globals/locals if primitive types. In C++ if you don't delcare something global, it doesn't auto initialise and you need to initialise it manually `int inpt = 0` i.e. it will cost you extra 3-4 assembly lines. I believe same is true for Java. See the answer by `@weston` below.

Comment: @hagubear c doesn't initialise locals. Primitive or not has nothing to do with it. Java doesn't init either, but Java will not compile if attempt to use an uninitialised variable.

Comment: http://ideone.com/TWtRYD why does this work then? You should say anything outside main (if declared locally) won't be initialised automatically.

Comment: @hagubear You're relying on [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). It appears to work in that case on that compiler. But it's not guaranteed to always work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Local

*Assuming no compiler optimisations are active*:

If the statements are local to a function, the one with `= 0` will cause an explicit initialisation step so the program will be longer and it will therefore take longer to execute.

### Global

If the statements are global, the `= 0` is implied, because `inpt` resides in the [BSS part of the Data Segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment#BSS) which is presumably block zeroed as the program loads. So there is no additional runtime cost for initialising globals to zero.